# Remove specific string in Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've searched and tried everything I could on here but couldn't find the exact thing I'm looking for.

I want to remove everything that has this pattern.

Word Word (1) > Word Word (2) > Word Word (3)

What I want to remove is Word Word (1) > Word Word (2) > and just leave Word Word (3)

There could be several of these strings on a single line so I'm trying to find an expression that will grab just the first and second string pattern leaving the third. Also before the (#) there could be more than 2 words.

I tried something along the lines of

```
 [A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+\([0-2]\)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

If someone could point me to a tutorial or explain how I would get the results I'm looking for that would be great. Thanks .

Comment: Please provide some actual sample text and the output you'd like to obtain from that text, rather than the repeated `Word word` content.

Comment: Red a couple examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([A-Za-z]+\s)+\(\d\)\s[>]\s`

Sample: 
[image]

Comment: What did you record this with? I needed to use software like this today.

Comment: this worked, can you explain the logic behind what you did? Thank you

Comment: "attempts and mistakes" ^_^ see the diagram: http://www.regexplained.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run a find and replace on 
^.+>.+>  and replace it with blank text